ZPL2 Label Printing on right side of ribbon vs left
I have created a program to print zpl2 by sending it via a socket to the zebra printer. This has had no problems until recently. We have decided to invert the label ( 180' rotation) and new problems have occurred. Rather than printing on the left side of the ribbon where the label is located it now prints on the right side of the ribbon where labels are not fed. How can I remedy this?

^XA 
^MUd,600,600
^PW 407
^POI
^FX QR for MAC Address^FS 
^FO66,24 
^BQN,2,10,H
^FDQA,{QR Info}^FS 
^FX Mac Address ^FS
^FO36,348 
^A0N,70,42 
^FD{mac} | {check}^FS 
^XZ


Try setting print width ^PW to the width of the label (in dots).

Adding ^PW moves the origin from the bottom right corner to the middle. How can I move it to the left?

That should have worked.  Check your printer settings in the control panel and see if the width is different there.  You can also try label home ^LH to move "right", which when inverted, should move the label left.
